# Modulus and Triangles in Complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC7z6.png)

Let z1, z2 and z3 be complex numbers such that |z1| = |z2| = |z3| = |z1 + z2+ z3| = 2. If |z1 - z2| = |z1 - z3| and
z2 ≠ z3. Then find the value of |z1 + z2||z1 + z3|.

In the question i went about plotting the complex numbers on circle of radius 2 and center origin and soon realized that the circle is the circumcenter of triangle and triangle is isosceles .And also the centroid is 2/3 distance from circumcenter(origin) .despite able to extract this much from the question I am not sure how to find the answer of the question I mean the question doesn't seem like they are asking the product of the distance between Z1 and Z2 and Z1 and Z3 So i am basically stuck .

Here obviously we can solve the question by taking values for the complex numbers But i want to know a proper method.

The answer is :8
and the hint given is :
The triangle has circumcentre at origin and its orthocentre lying
on the circumcircle.

Comment: qn should be typed out

Comment: Please use Mathjax to type your problem. In your case its relatively simple. `$|z_1+z_2+z_3|=2$` yields $|z_1+z_2+z_3|=2$.

Comment: My **2nd** (**not 1st**) try, which is a lot of trouble, is to set $~z_a = (x_a + iy_a)~: ~a \in \{1,2,3\}~$ and see where this leads.  My **1st try** (re **intuition**) would (instead) be to  consider: [1] $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are all points on the circle, centered at the origin of radius $2$. [2] $z_1$ is on the perpendicular bisector between $z_2$ and $z_3$. [3] (**Unproven**) it looks like $|z_2 + z_3| = 0$.  Following this approach, I would first **use** [3] to see where it leads, and then try to **prove** [3].

Comment: Ok, its this is the first time i am hearing such kind of a approach

Comment: Suggestion: divide all three values by $z_1$, and solve the problem of $|w_2| = |w_3| = |1 + w_2 + w_3| = 1$ and $|1 - w_2| = |1 -w_3|$ and $w_2 \ne w_3$. Therefore $w_2, w_3$ are the two solutions to $|w|^2 = 1, |w - 1|^2 = r^2$ for some $r$. Then it is a matter of figuring out which $r$ gives $|1 + w_2  + w_3| = 1$.

Comment: Please do not use the complex geometry tag. It has an entirely different meaning.